# Apache beam write transform writes into multiple files?

Tags: java, apache-beam

I was looking at the wordCount example from [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#wordcount-example) 
 and when I tried to run this example in local, it wrote the counts into multiple files. I created a test project to read and write data from a file and even that write operation wrote the output in to multiple files. How do I get the result in just a single file? I am using direct runner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is happening for performance reasons. You should be able to force a single file by using [TextIO.Write.withoutSharding](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Write.html#withoutSharding--)

> **withoutSharding**
>
> public TextIO.Write withoutSharding()
>
> Forces a single file as output and empty shard name template. This
>   option is only compatible with unwindowed writes.
>
> For unwindowed writes, constraining the number of shards is likely to
>   reduce the performance of a pipeline. Setting this value is not
>   recommended unless you require a specific number of output files.
>
> This is equivalent to .withNumShards(1).withShardNameTemplate("")

Comment: Thank you that worked. But, the sequence is out of order. Is there a way we can read and write to the file in a sequence?

Comment: Might be worth a separate question with a short code example and explanation why the order matters.

Comment: Sure will do that